# Using AIC to compare distributional assumptions?

Tags: model-selection, goodness-of-fit, aic

[image]

[image]

These are two QQ plots of my residuals after fitting a model, with the exact same structure, except that the first model used one distribution A, and the other uses distribution B (normal, vs gamma, actually).

However, the global deviance of the A-model is less than the B-model, and using AIC, I get that A-model has a smaller AIC value than B-model.

Um, why?

Comment: @SmallChess, QQ stands for "quantile-quantile", and it uses a whole range of quantiles rather than just quartiles.

Comment: Lower AIC indicates better fit. The more the QQ plot resembles a 1-to-1 line, the better the fit. There is no contradiction here.